# How can I streamline Google Script onEdit() code taking 8 seconds to run?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm working to automatically collect usernames when they request items. It is currently taking around 8 seconds to run the following code, with just 1 user. I'm looking at having up to 36 different users using it and worry that it will either time out or cause errors with that many users.

I want it to add users and a timestamp when making a request and delete both when the request has been deleted.

```
function onEdit(e) {
  const lock = LockService.getScriptLock();
  var row = e.range.getRow();
  var col = e.range.getColumn();
  var s = e.source.getActiveSheet().getName();
  var user = Session.getActiveUser().getUsername();
  
  
  lock.tryLock(15000);

if(lock.hasLock()){
  if(((col === 3 || col === 9 || col === 15 || col === 21) && s === "Study Hall Requests")){

  if(typeof e.value !== 'undefined'){
    e.source.getActiveSheet().getRange(row,col+1,1,2).setValues([[new Date(),user]]);
    lock.releaseLock();
  }else{
    e.source.getActiveSheet().getRange(row,col+1,1,2).clearContent();
    lock.releaseLock();
  }
}
```

}}

Comment: Provide debugging details: Use `console.time()` to provide the part where execution takes the longest.

Comment: It looks like my first if statement is taking the longest part at about 2/3 of the time now, 850 ms and the time from before if to completion is 1182 ms.

Comment: Replace `var row = e.range.getRow();
  var col = e.range.getColumn();` with `e.range.rowStart , e.range.columnStart`

Comment: I wouldn't use lock for an onEdit() the reality is that multiple users will have problems no matter what you do.  They just are not that quick at reacting.  A 15 second delay with a 30 second timeout seems a  bit of a stretch to me.  You might want to consider an installable trigger instead.

Comment: `e.source.getActiveSheet().getRange(row,col+1,1,2).setValues();` to `e.range.offset(0,1,1,2).setValues()[[new Date(),user]]`

Comment: I don't understand why the need to use `lock`. The script simply adds the date and user on the next 2 columns. This code should not take 8 seconds to run at a first glance. Unless I'm missing something here.

Comment: Also 1180ms is just 1.1s not 8s

Comment: I'm wondering if I had a slow connection for a while that was delaying it. It seams to sit between 1 to 3 seconds now.

Comment: Thank you everyone for your help, I removed the lock, and it seems to be running smoother now.